# unable to start tomcat with maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

while starting tomcat with maven, getting following error

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/web_store]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>   component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/web_store]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping
>   specifies an unknown servlet name dispatcherServlet-servlet   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3180)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1376)
>
> Aug 10, 2016 2:28:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)

I am using maven and getting error[image: on this project strcture]
while starting tomcat is running normally but when I run project with tomcat it shows following error

**Edit**

**1 web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>webstore</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>view/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**2 dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="web_store.*" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: and dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

Comment: @NicolasFilotto , please check I added files

Comment: `<servlet-name>`  has to be same in both `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In your servlet mapping, you need to refer to a servlet that has been defined in your `web.xml` and here only `dispatcherServlet` has been defined so simply rename `dispatcherServlet-servlet` into `dispatcherServlet` in your servlet mapping as next:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: unfortunately that led me to another error `IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]` **not able to find bean.xml**

Comment: So try to rename dispatcherServlet into dispatcherServlet-servlet in both place in your web.xml then

Comment: but as per maven resource files are supposed to be found when declared under resource folder

Comment: i changed both to `dispatcherSerlet` solved the error , can you guide me on how to solve this one

Comment: try to move dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml into src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Comment: thank you sir, i have few more queries regarding this , if I may ask